# What kind of convergence is in Gateaux derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $F$ map $X$ to another Banach space $Y$. The usual (one sided) directional derivative of $F$ at $x$ in the direction $v$ is 
$$F'(x;v)=\lim_{t\downarrow0}\frac{F(x+tv)-F(x)}{t}\qquad(1)$$
when this limit exists. If $F'(x;\cdot)\in\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ then (denoting $DF(x)=F'(x;\cdot)$) $DF(x)$ is Gâteaux derivative. My question is: what kind of convergence is in (1)? Is it pointwise convergence?

If we consider convergence with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|_{Y}$, i.e.,
$$\lim_{t\downarrow0}\|F'(x;v)-\frac{F(x+tv)-F(x)}{t}\|_{Y}=0$$ 
and once again $F'(x;\cdot)\in\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$, I think we obtain Fréchet derivative. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Gâteaux derivative you are taking the limit of
$$\Bbb R\longrightarrow Y$$
$$t\longmapsto\frac{F(x + tv) - F(x)}{t}$$
for *each* $x$, so the convergence is pointwise. *But* you are considering $Y$ endowed with its norm, so the existence of both of your limits is *equivalent*.

In the Fréchet derivative you are asking if exists and is zero the limit of
$$X\longrightarrow Y$$
$$h\longmapsto\frac{\|F(x + h) - F(x) - F'(x)h\|_Y}{\|h\|_X}$$
for some linear continuous function
$$F'(x):X\longrightarrow Y.$$